# How do I create a text channel discord.js 14

Tags: javascript, server, discord, discord.js, bots

I wanted to ask how to create channels in discord.js 14 (i tried to researched but found nothing) I want to make a simple text channel! :)) Also, with the stuff i found, it worked ( no errors) it just didnt create anything / post errors in debug log

Comment: Have you actually looked into discord.js documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It's literally under Discord.js documentation. Please, next time before asking a question read the docs.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome

```
   guild.channels.create({
        name: "hello",
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        parent: cat[0].ID,
        // your permission overwrites or other options here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//If the command is slash type

const { Permissions } = require("discord.js")

interaction.guild.channels.create({
    name: "new-channel",
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: interaction.guild.id,
            accept: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
        },
    ],
});

//If the command is message type

const { Permissions } = require("discord.js")

message.guild.channels.create({
    name: "new-channel",
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: message.guild.id,
            accept: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
        },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: isnt this discord.js 13?